# ASP.NET Wizard control display button in English despite button.Text is in French

Tags: asp.net, controls, wizard

I have an ASP.NET web form application in French and everything is in french.

In one aspx page, I have an ASP:Wizard control that display NEXT instead of the french translation SUIVANT.

My web server has been installed in English (2008 R2 server) but I have changed all local settings to French (date, keyboard, location for my profile but also to any future profile and to the system account)
I have rebooted the server to apply the new settings.

The server menus and window messages are in French.

I have translated the properties of the wizard to French like this :
StartNextButton.Text = "suivant"
FinishCompleteButton.Text = "Terminer"

My next and finish button are being displayed in English instead of French.
I have also tried in localhost and the wizard buttons are always in English.

Here is my code:

```
protected void WzdReport_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.wzdReport.StepNextButtonText = "Suivant";
        this.wzdReport.StartNextButtonText = "Suivant";
        switch (this.wzdReport.ActiveStepIndex)
        {
            case 0:this.LoadField(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.hdfRequestId.Value) ? this.hdfRequestId.Value : string.Empty);
                break;
            case 1:
                if (this.ckbStatic.Checked)
                {
                    this.LoadDependantRequest(this.txtCodeRequest.Text);
                }

                break;
        }
    }
```

Do you know why ?
Is there a solution ?

Comment: Have you set the properties of the wizard control on the aspx page for the button text?  For instance:
`<asp:Wizard ID="wzdReport" runat="server" StartNextButtonText="Suivant" StepNextButtonText="Suivant" ...`

Comment: Thanks Justin, it works by translating all step buttons in the declaration of the wizard control in the ASPX page. But how do you globalize the button's text if your site has several languages ?

Comment: John, for multi-language support take a look at using resource files: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials, I found out that I can define the text in the code behind in the Page_Init method instead of the aspx page. It is better if I want to localize the strings like this :

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.wzdReport.StartNextButtonText = "Suivant";
        this.wzdReport.StepNextButtonText = "Suivant";
        this.wzdReport.FinishPreviousButtonText = "Précédent";
        this.wzdReport.StepPreviousButtonText = "Précédent";
        this.wzdReport.FinishCompleteButtonText = "Terminer";
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work when I place the above code in Page_Load but it does work ok in the Page_Init event.